# Grouping the List of json of different types as per their type in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json list of Different Type of objects (Schemaless). however, every row contains the Type of the structure. I need to group it as per their type.
I need to group this Json.
Input is below

```
 var result =   [{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "Type":"Person" },
    { "fruit":"apple", "Type":"Diet" },
    { "length":100, "width":60, "height":30,, "Type":"Measure" },
    { "firstName":"Shivang", "lastName":"Mittal", "Type":"Person" }]
```

Expected Output:

```
    var persons=   [{ "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "Type":"Person" }, 
                    { "firstName":"Shivang", "lastName":"Mittal", "Type":"Person" }];

    var Diets = [{ "fruit":"apple", "Type":"Diet" }];
    var Measures = [{ "length":100, "width":60, "height":30,, "Type":"" }];
```

How can i group it based on their Type in c#?

Comment: What do you want as result? Json? C# objects?

Comment: @greenhoorn : Json Iteself, in diff groups. So basically i need to segregate it by type

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: Sorry, my bad. corrected

Comment: You could make the question clearer... anyhow have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685829/using-group-by-type-of-operation-on-json-objects

Comment: Then have a read of using http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to achieve grouping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698175/what-is-the-json-net-equivilant-of-xmls-xpath-selectnodes-selectsinglenode

Comment: @PaulZahra : My Json list is not having a same schema. every row can have a different schema. "Type" column spcify the type of the row

Comment: @PaulZahra : let me edit my question for more clarity

Comment: @Shiv It is possible using the JSon.Net SelectToken method and the JSon Linq that JSon.Net provides, and use the JPath to the Type, I'm sorry but I don't have time to work it out for you.

Comment: @PaulZahra: No problem, I will go through this and let you know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using strongly-typed objects/changing schema:

```
  var jarray = JArray.Parse(@"[{ ""firstName"":""John"", ""lastName"":""Doe"", ""Type"":""Person"" },
{ ""fruit"":""apple"", ""Type"":""Diet"" },
{ ""length"":100, ""width"":60, ""height"":30, ""Type"":""Measure"" },
{ ""firstName"":""Shivang"", ""lastName"":""Mittal"", ""Type"":""Person"" }]");

  var query = jarray
    .GroupBy(g => g["Type"])
    .Select(g => string.Format("var {0}={1};{2}", g.Key, new JArray(g.ToList()), Environment.NewLine));
  string result = string.Join(string.Empty, query);
```

Answer (score 1):

better for you will be change your json format:

```
{
   "Customer": [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "Type":"Person" }],
   "Fruit": [{"fruit":"apple", "Type":"Diet" }],
   "Length": [{"length":100, "width":60, "height":30, "Type":"Measure" }]
}
```

and then it will be easy

```
public class JsonType()
{
    public CustomerType Customer {get; set;}
    public FruitType Fruit {get; set;}
    public LengthType Length {get; set;}
}

public class CustomerType()
{
    public string firstName {get; set;}
    public string lastName {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}

public class FruitType()
{
    public string fruit {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```

etc...

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonType>(yourJson);
```

Comment: nice suggestion. But for that i need to change the end point ( service returning the json ). It will be a time taking work around to change the service